# How to pipeline requests in a proxy-like netty application

Tags: multithreading, tcp, netty

I am trying to write a proxy-like application with netty4, and I am wondering if I can establish only one Channel connected with one backend server instance instead of one Channel per frontend connection (as the netty-example does).

Here is something confusing me. basically I want to pipeline my upcoming frontend requests from different connections to my single channel to backend server. we know that Channel.write() is thread-safe, and this is good. So I am trying to approach it with similar technic in HttpContentCompressor (which keep Accept-Encoding header in a queue).

it would be something like:

```
public class Request {
  RequestBody body;
  ChannelHandlerContext frontContext;
}

public class ProxyCodec extends MessageToMessageCodec<Request, ByteBuf> {
  Queue<Request> pendingRequests;
  ...
  protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Request msg, List<Object> out)
        throws Exception {
    pendingRequest.add(msg);
    out.add(myEncoder.encode(msg.getBody()));
  }

  protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out)
        throws Exception {
    Request pendingRequest = pendingRequests.poll();
    pendingRequest.getFrontContext().writeAndFlush(myDecoder.decode(msg));
  }
}
```

so we put this ProxyCodec to our backend channel pipeline, and write all requests through it, then expecting it would dispatch response to the correct frontend context.

while I am not sure if it will work or not. should the pendingRequests queue be thread safe? are the requests through this handler keeping the same order with they written to the backend server?

or any better idea for accomplishing this?

Thanks

---

update:

seems like outbound handlers could be invoked concurrently by non-IO threads. to solve this problem, is it a good idea to add a multi-producer-single-consumer queue between my front/backend channel so only the single consumer thread would invoke the ProxyCodec?

Answer (score 0):

No it must no be Thread-safe in Netty 4 as all will be handled by the EventLoop that is assigned to the Channel thats ChannelPipeline holds the ProxyCodec

Comment: then what about we share the same eventLoop with in/out bound channel?